# PHP and CHMOD question

Tags: php, linux, unix, permissions, chmod

I want my PHP software to be able to auto update. For this to work, I need PHP to be able to write into files both existing and non-existing (create). Will it always work if I just CHMOD the target files to be 0777 and then write into it? Or does the PHP/Apache/wtvr process need to be the owner of the file?

Sometimes when people upload using an FTP account, the owner might be different from the PHP process, is this a problem?

Edit: I'm building a PHP application, I can't know on which configurations the app will run on, and I can't modify any server related settings. I can do what PHP can do, like chown(), chmod().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have one server where, when files are uploaded through FTP, the ownership of the file changes to the ftp user which has caused a few permission problems in the past.

We use groups to get round this

For example, you could create a usergroup for accessing the files and add apache plus each of your ftp users to the group:

```
usermod -a -G appUpdaters www
usermod -a -G appUpdaters ftp1
usermod -a -G appUpdaters ftp2
etc...
```

Then you can chown the file/folders to a user + group and chmod to 775

```
chown www.appUpdaters foldername
chmod 775 foldername
```

That way if the ownership changes to ftp1.appUpdaters or ftp2.appUpdaters, the other users can still write to the file.

Like I say, I don't seem to need this on all the servers I use so I guess whether you do or not depends on your server config.  If you do decide to use groups tho, I find this link comes in handy sometimes

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-add-user-to-group/

Comment: I think there's a problem. I don't think I can create user groups via PHP? Don't I need an access to the server? I'm just a developer, writing software for multiple platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Make the folder that you want to upload into owned by your www server. Then your php script will be able to write into that folder if it's chmodded 755.

```
# chown www somefolder
# chmod 755 !$
```

(Don't make other stuff in your web files owned by www).

Comment: Is there a way to find out the www user via PHP?

Comment: Make a folder chmod 777, and then make a small php script to write a file in that folder then ls -l and see the owner of the file, I guess. There are easier ways though. Do you have root access?